# Weak event pattern in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

In WPF, there are some classes such as `PropertyChangedEventManager` and `CollectionChangedEventManager` which derive from `WeakEventManager` aiming to implement weak event pattern. Through weak event pattern, the memory leak problem in the normal event has been solved.

But I cannot find these classes in UWP SDK, since UWP also needs to handle `PropertyChanged` event of `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `CollectionChanged` event of `INotifyCollectionChanged` in data binding, so how does UWP solve the event memory leak problem?

Answer (score 2):

The [UWP Community Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit) has a [WeakEventListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/helpers/WeakEventListener).  Would that work for you?

[Example here](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/UnitTests/Helpers/Test_WeakEventListener.cs):

```
        WeakEventListener<SampleClass, object, EventArgs> weak = new WeakEventListener<SampleClass, object, EventArgs>(sample);

        weak.OnEventAction = (instance, source, eventArgs) => { isOnEventTriggered = true; };

        weak.OnDetachAction = (listener) => { isOnDetachTriggered = true; };


        sample.Raisevent += weak.OnEvent;
```

Comment: Thanks, this class is provided by a third-party library. Furthermore, to implement weak event pattern, as far as I know, `WeakEventManager` class is needed. So what I want to know is how UWP SDK itself solve the memory leak problem in data binding and whether there is an implementation of weak event pattern in UWP to solve that problem.